# Is it possible to include raw assets into air native extension?

Tags: android, flash, air, assets, ane

I know different ways to add raw assets (which are placed in assets folder, not res folder) to your AIR application (one for Flash Pro and Adobe Animate, second for Flash Builder and so on).

But I'm interested, is there any way to include raw assets into ane plugin? Again, I know about accessing native resources with R.* mechanism, but it isn't that I looking for.